Laravel Queues do not work on production server
Faced with this problem:
On a locally deployed server (Laravel Herd), I created a Job that gets the track number of an order from the delivery service API.
I specified QUEUE_CONNECTION=database in .env and also executed:
php artisan queue:table
php artisan queue:batches-table
php artisan notifications:table
php artisan migrate
And locally I have everything working fine! I just ran the php artisan queue:work command and when I ran Job, entries like:
2024-07-11 16:18:27 App\Jobs\FetchCdekOrderInfo ... RUNNING
2024-07-11 16:18:28 App\Jobs\FetchCdekOrderInfo ... DONE
But when posting to the production server, there were some difficulties. I did all the same actions as described above, all the code and project settings are exactly the same, but when I execute the php artisan queue:work command, now it just says INFO Processing jobs from the [default] queue and that's it. Jobs do not work, no entries appear in the terminal.
Could you please tell me what could be the problem? How to configure Queues on production server?
If additional information or code is needed, please advise.
The database is MySql
Server Settings:
Laravel 10.48.11
Apache 2.4.58
Nginx 1.25.4
I tried clearing the cache, restarting the server, changing QUEUEUE_CONNECTION to redis, and putting the command execution through Supervisor

Can you check if the jobs table has any jobs or not? I think the issue is not with the queue but with the code of your job.

The records in the Jobs table appear correctly, but are not processed. If there were problems with the Job code, this would be reflected in the logs.

I suggest you use sync for the queue connection for now and change it later if everything works.
